# An observable is called an event if it has no subscribers. Is it True Or False

Tags: angular, rxjs

I was asked this question recently. I know the difference between cold and hot observables and the definition of events. Is the above statement correct?

Answer (score 1):

An event is still an event even if nothing is set up to react to it. Observables are streams that broadcast an event has happened. Observables themselves are never events, they emit when an event happens and have listeners that react to the event. Your question is invalid as the observable is never an event but a stream of events so it is not a true/false question.

Comment: Thank you, this question came in an interview shortlisting round. The original question was - An HTTPClient Observable(Angular) is called an event or not if it has no subscribers.